# How to properly insert data into a postgres table?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

I'm using the following to try and insert a record into a postgresql database table, but it's not working. I don't get any errors, but there are no records in the table. I do commit at the end of my code as well. What could it possibly be? It's frustrating since I am not getting any syntax error in my code.

Excuse me for my lack of knowledge, As I am fairly new to Python.

Here is the code:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(host=config.DB_HOST, database=config.DB_NAME, user=config.DB_USER, password=config.DB_PASS, port=config.DB_PORT)

cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

cursor.execute("select * from stock where is_etf = TRUE")

etfs = cursor.fetchall()

dates = ['2022-08-23', '2022-08-24']

for current_date in dates:
    for etf in etfs:
        print(etf['symbol'])
        
        with open(f"new/{current_date}/{etf['symbol']}.csv") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            next(reader)
            for row in reader:
                if len(row) == 8:
                    ticker = row[3]
                                   
                    if ticker:
                        shares = row[5]
                        weight = row[7]
                        
                        cursor.execute("""
                            SELECT * FROM stock WHERE symbol = %s
                        """, (ticker,))
                        stock = cursor.fetchone()
                        if stock:                        
                            cursor.execute("""
                                INSERT INTO etf_holding (etf_id, holding_id, dt, shares, weight)
                                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                            """, (etf['id'], stock['id'], current_date, shares, weight))
                
                
connection.commit()
```

as a result I get this:

[image: results]

This is the unpopulated table:

[image: Etf Table]

Comment: Possible reasons are looping over empty collections and failing`if` checks.  Step through the code with a debugger to check that it is executing as you expect, or add a `print` call after each `for` or `if` statement to trace the execution of the code.

Comment: are you sure the line that executes the insert is actually reached?

Comment: 1) Are you sure the script is connecting to the same database and/or the correct schema in the database that you are looking for results in the GUI frontend? 2)  Given the `next(reader)` I'm assuming the CSV file has a header. If that is the case why not use `csv.DictReader` and fetch values directly  using the header keys? Something like `ticker = row['ticker']`, assuming `ticker` is the header name.